# Is there a limit on the size of variables returned by web services to a Java web start application?

Tags: java, web-services

I have a program that calls some web services. The web service being called returns a string that contains the content of an xml file. This is a very long string. When the client is run from within Netbeans as a regular jar the string is returned in full and everything works fine. But when the client is run using java web start (jnlp file) only part of the string is returned. The string is always being cut at the exact same position. It seems that there is an upper limit on the length of a returned string when using java web start. When this limit is reached then the connection is abruptly cut and only part of the string is returned, hence the "connection aborted" error. How can I change/increase this limit?

Comment: having such a long response might make your functionality unreliable, does it make sense to split the response in parts/page and make request specify the part/page that you need next ?

Comment: The responses are only one page long. There are no two page responses. Even thought they are one page long the string is not being returned in full.

Comment: for you a page is how long ? anyhow I still believe that you should split the response o make that content available as a link for the user/consumer of the response

Answer (score 0):

Having such a long response might make your functionality unreliable, does it make sense to split the response in parts/page and make request specify the part/page that you need next

Another alternative is to make the content available as a link to be downloaded

More discussion on the subject can be found here 
http://www.coderanch.com/t/221516/Web-Services/java/XML-Web-Service-response-maximum

Comment: The problem only occurs when I use Java web start. Otherwise everything is fine. The solution has something to do with Java web start. I don't want to change how I send the data since it is already working when I create the program jar. I want to know why the same doesn't work with Java web start.

Comment: @user3245747 so the title and most of what your are asking makes anyone believe you are asking something else